# How to load a DLL from a different folder?

Tags: c++, dll

I'm using several large Third Party DLLs that I would like to place in a separate folder from the main application and load them from there at runtime. These DLLs are over 5GB in size all together (mainly PyTorch C++). I have several versions of my application installed, all using the same version of the Third Party DLLs, so I would like to save both disk space and installation time.

My application has several processes that use these DLLs, some are Managed (C# .NET) and some are Native C++.
I have an unmanaged DLL that uses the large DLLs, and this unmanaged DLL is used in a managed application using C++ Managed.
I also have a native application that uses the large DLLs directly.

I tried using [AddDllDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory) by adding a DllMain to my unmanaged DLL, but when running the application I got the missing DLL error before the DllMain was called.
When I used AddDllDirectory from managed code at the startup of the application it worked.
But this means I need to use AddDllDirectory in the startup of every process I run, instead of just in one place.
This solution is also not working for the native application. I tried using AddDllDirectory in the main of the native application, but again I got the missing DLL error before I got to the main.

I tried using [Delay Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170), but that also didn't work. I could see that the large DLLs are marked as delay load by using DumpBin, but when I ran the native application I got the missing DLL error again. I tried to implement [a Failure Hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/error-handling-and-notification?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019#notification-hooks) but it wasn't called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Microsoft says https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order

Comment: ***What am I doing wrong?*** Probably not adding an entry in the windows `PATH` environment variable so that your OS can find the dlls when it searches for the dependent dlls.

Comment: @Eljay, I've read the article you linked. In it they explain about AddDllDirectory which I used, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @drescherjm, I'm trying to avoid using the PATH environment variable, that's the whole point. If I modify the PATH I wouldn't need any of the methods I listed in my post. I have several version of my application, some using the same Third Party DLLs, and some using different versions of them. I don't want to change the PATH before changing versions.

Comment: If you can't modify the PATH, your choices are: 1) put the DLLs that are in the PATH, 2) put the DLLs with the application, 3) use the fully qualified path to the DLLs, 4) the registry as per the Microsoft link, 5) ???

Comment: So what's the purpose of the AddDllDirectory function?

Comment: The document in the first link discusses the `AddDllDirectory` behavior in a 2 places at the bottom: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-using-load_library_search-flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-using-load_library_search-flags) I have not used this as I usually set the PATH or put the dlls in the same folder or use redirection.